# python regex BESTMATCH behaviour

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy-search

I am seeing a behaviour of the python regex library for fuzzy matching that I do not quite understand.

The string I am searching into is:

```
s="TACGGTTTTAACTTTGCAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATTACTAGCAGTAAAAATGCGGAAATTTCTCTTTATGATGGCGCCACGCTCAATTTGGCTTCAAACAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGTCAAG"
```

and the patterns I am searching for are (5 mismatches allowed):

```
for match in regex.finditer("(CAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATCACTAGCGATAAA|GGCTTCAAGCAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGT|AATTTCTCTTTATGAT){s<=5}", s):
    print(match)
```

My three patterns are found, as expected, using the command above:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(16, 46), match='CAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATTACTAGCAGTAAA', fuzzy_counts=(3, 0, 0)>
<regex.Match object; span=(54, 70), match='AATTTCTCTTTATGAT'>
<regex.Match object; span=(87, 120), match='GGCTTCAAACAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGT', fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 0)>
```

However if I ask for the best match, the first pattern (starting CAAGCTT) is not found anymore:

```
for match in regex.finditer("(?b)(CAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATCACTAGCGATAAA|GGCTTCAAGCAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGT|AATTTCTCTTTATGAT){s<=5}", s):
    print(match)
<regex.Match object; span=(54, 70), match='AATTTCTCTTTATGAT'>
<regex.Match object; span=(87, 120), match='GGCTTCAAACAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGT', fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 0)>
```

How can I explain this, as my patterns are not overlapping and, if I search for them separately, using bestmatch, they are found indeed!?

EDIT

If I modify my string so that the first pattern only has 1 mismatch left (doesn't work with 2), and remove the third pattern from my search, my first pattern will be found along with the second:

```
s="TACGGTTTTAACTTTGCAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATCACTAGCGGTAAAAATGCGGAAATTTCTCTTTATGATGGCGCCACGCTCAATTTGGCTTCAAACAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGTCAAG"
for match in regex.finditer("(?b)(CAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATCACTAGCGATAAA|GGCTTCAAGCAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGT){s<=5}", s):
   print(match)
<regex.Match object; span=(16, 46), match='CAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATCACTAGCGGTAAA', fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 0)>
<regex.Match object; span=(87, 120), match='GGCTTCAAACAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGT', fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 0)>
```

Is there an unwritten rule of regex provided no more than two best matches, with no more than 1 mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your output. When running:

```
for match in regex.finditer("(CAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATCACTAGCGATAAA|GGCTTCAAGCAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGT|AATTTCTCTTTATG){s<=5}", s):
    print(match)
```

I retrieve:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(16, 46), match='CAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATTACTAGCAGTAAA', fuzzy_counts=(3, 0, 0)>
<regex.Match object; span=(54, 68), match='AATTTCTCTTTATG'>
<regex.Match object; span=(82, 96), match='AATTTGGCTTCAAA', fuzzy_counts=(5, 0, 0)>
```

Or to have a bit more insight:

[image]

If I compare this to your output I can see that the last match has an overlapping position with your 3rd match. Since there is no overlapping allowed matching left to right the 3rd result in my table above should come first and cancel out your 3rd match.

That being said, if read carefully I think you want to retrieve three matches? The best match for each of your sub-patterns. I don't think a (non)capture group will actually do what you are after.

All it will do is return the best matches within the string compared to *any of the 3 subpatterns*. So it might just return 2 or more substrings that match the exact same subpattern within your expression. What the engine will do: start a 1st match left to right. Then immediately discard this match if a better one is found to the right of this 1st match. This mechanism will stop when no better match can be found.

When no better match is found however, your code will continue trying to return matches from the position to the right of your 1st match and follow the same logic over and over untill the end of the input is reached. You can test this by adding the substring 'AATTTCTCTTTATGAT' at the start of the string variable. You'll notice that instead of 2 matches, the engine will return three! Yet, two of them are the exact same.

Secondly, you won't have an escape for the possibility you won't find any match. So, instead of nesting these in a single pattern, run over a given list of subpatterns:

```
import regex as re
s="TACGGTTTTAACTTTGCAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATTACTAGCAGTAAAAATGCGGAAATTTCTCTTTATGATGGCGCCACGCTCAATTTGGCTTCAAACAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGTCAAG"
r_in = ['CAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATCACTAGCGATAAA', 'GGCTTCAAGCAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGT', 'AATTTCTCTTTATG']
r_new = [mtch[0] if bool(mtch) else '' for mtch in [re.search(fr'(?b)({el}){{s<=5:[ACGT]}}', s) for el in r_in]]
print(r_new)
```

Gives:

```
['CAAGCTTCAGAAGGGATTACTAGCAGTAAA', 'GGCTTCAAACAGCGTTAAATTAATGGGTAATGT', 'AATTTCTCTTTATG']
```

Note that I also edited the 'fuzziness' to be more explicit using `{s<=5:[ACGT]}`.

Comment: Thanks! There was an error in the last pattern, in that it was missing two characters. I have edited/corrected my question. How do you see the patterns are overlapping? If I look at the start and end positions of the matches, it seems they are located at different regions of the string s? Or aren't they? Great to have this alternative way of doing things! I will keep it in mind and use it if needed. I would still like to know why bestmatch returns matches with 0 and 1 mismatch(es) but not with 3, even though it is less than the allowed 5.

Comment: And you're right when saying that my objective is to get the bestmatch for each of my patterns, as long as there is max 5 mismatches (each). What the method you have shown above is doing it seems!

Comment: @Agathe, hopefully the edited answer makes things clear.

Comment: thanks! It makes more sense now. Will try the suggested test on Thursday and let you know.